# Difference between a "movement" and a "campaign"

Tags: meaning, differences

A campaign means:

> an organized course of action to achieve a goal

A movement means:

> a group of people working together to advance their shared political, social, or artistic ideas

Are there any differences between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meanings overlap, obviously. Here's Arlo Guthrie's take on it in [Alice's Restaurant...](http://www.metrolyrics.com/alices-restaurant-massacre-lyrics-arlo-guthrie.html)

> You know, if one person, just one person does it [the psychiatrists] may think he's really sick and they won't take him.
>   And if two people, *two* people do it (in harmony), they may think they're both faggots and they won't take either of them.
>   And if three people do it, can you imagine, *three* people walking in, singin' a bar of Alice's Restaurant and walking out?  They may think it's an **organization**.
>    And can you, can you imagine fifty people a day,I said *fifty people a day* walking in singin' a bar of Alice's Restaurant and walking out? Friends they may thinks it's a **movement**.

I'm sure even after almost 50 years, more than 50 people a day sing a bar of *Alice's Restaurant* (though probably not in psychiatrists' offices! :). The point is it could be classed as an *organisation* (or *movement*) simply on the basis of many (or *very* many) people acting in a "coordinated" way.

But in order to be classed as a **campaign**, a "movement" would need to have one or more *specific goals*. Normally, goals which can only be achieved by appealing to others whose support is vital to the advancement of ["the cause"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cause) (sense 2 there).

In short, for those specific contexts where the two words overlap, to the extent that they *might* be used with slightly different senses (bearing in mind that very often, they're *not*), that difference primarily hinges on the implications of OP's two definitions. People in a **campaign** know (and usually publicize) what they're trying to achieve. People in a **movement** are simply like-minded (but may not be very clear - or even consistent - about what if anything they want to change).